# Derivative on both sides.

Tags: derivatives

I've got a problem understanding how derivative works when I want to differentiate both sides.

For example $y = x^2$, When I multiply something both sides let's say by 2 then it looks like that : $2y = 2x^2$.
When I want to differentiate both sides then it looks like that : $ydx = x^2 dx$
I found a basic formulas

[image]

So derivative of $x^2 dx$ is $2x$ but derivative of $y dx$ ? I don't know how to interpret it because it is derivative of "x" and not "y" so it is constant ? Then derivative of $y dx$ is $0$ ?
Even if I use $f(x)$ instead of $y$ it doesn't change much because I still need to make derivative both sides in which f(x) and y are not "x".
Because now f(x) and y are the same thing.

Sorry if what I said isn't clear I'll try to rewrite it if it's not clear.

EDIT :

Another example : $y^2 = x$
I have to get rid of this power so I square root in both sides and I get :
$\sqrt{y^2} = \sqrt{x}$
So it should be like this :
$|y| = \sqrt{x}$ Therefore $y = -\sqrt{x}$ or $y = \sqrt{x}$

So "y" here is a function but I work on him like on "x".
So why in derivative it works differently ?

Edit 2 :

Or for example let's have $y = sin(x) + 1$ and I changed $z = sin(x)$ so $y = z +1$ now I want to differentiate using "dx".

So $ydx = zdx + 0$ so is "z" a constant or not ?
Because Like in the picture above there is $dk/dx = 0$ which says that "k" is a constant. In some example where I was calculating things I also thought of some variables as an constant.

I am a bit confused.

Comment: The $f(x)$ interpretation is important because it shows that $y$ is both non-constant and dependent on $x$. Derivatives describe the relationship between the input $x$ and the output $y$ of a function so you have to keep that in mind when using them. It's a result about functions, not variables.

Comment: @CyclotomicField But I used the same rules when it comes to equallity of both sides. Like multiplying both, adding both sides, substracting both sides, exponentiation both sides. That's why I don't understand why "y" of "f(x)" here isn't derivated. Sorry for this silly question. But if I used "y" instead of "f(x)" in which "y" is a variable but says the same like "f(x)" but "f(x)" is not a variable I guess. I am a bit confused

Comment: @CyclotomicField Am I wrong or right ?

Comment: Differentiating with respect to $x$ on both sides will give require what's called implicit differentiation. It will be important when you learn about the chain rule. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function#Implicit_differentiation

Comment: @CyclotomicField 
I've edited my post take a look ;) Like it works when I square root both sides and it acts like it is like a normal parameter. Also PS question y(x) and y are the same thing right ? 
Also I read it, but I don't get it fully. For example if I had x,y,z parameters and derivated for "x" then "y" and "z" wouldn't be derivated as constance ?

Comment: @CyclotomicField What do you think about it ?

Comment: @CyclotomicField I've edited again the post.
And I still can't understand it. I don't know whether the variable is constant or not ...

Comment: If I say "The ratio is three to two" it makes sense but saying "the ratio is three to" doesn't. This is the same idea, you can't have the derivative without a relationship between $y$ and $x$. It's like a ratio, that's why we use fractional notation for it like $dy/dx$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what $y$ is exactly. If it is $y=f(x)$ then you couldn't simply find a formula for it since some functions couldn't be differentiated. If $y$ is a constant then the derivative is $0$. Also, in your example: $$y=\sin x+1=z+1$$Then $z$ is a function that is dependent on $x$, so differentiating it as a constant is incorrect. I will give you a formal definition to clear up your confusion:

> If $y$ depends on some coordinate then its derivative doesn't have to be $0$. If $y$ is independent of any coordinate then its derivative must be $0$.

Comment: So derivative works differently ? I thought that this rule that I multiply both sides or square root of both sides etc. would work here as well. And I couldn't understand exactly why it works this way. 
I was asking also about it because when I was doing partial derivatives like (x,y,z) a function for "z" in which is a function but then sometimes "y" is a constance or "x" is a constance. I couldn't understand it.

Comment: @Jackob2001 I also had the same confusion when I was learning partial derivatives. If the function is, say $x^2+y^2+z^2$ and you were asked to differentiate with respect to $z$, then $x$ and $y$ are constants. You are allowed to do regular arithmetic on equations like $y^2=x$ to get $y=\pm\sqrt{x}$ but when you differentiate both sides, the $y$ is actually an $f(x)$ in disguise.

Comment: Wierd before "y" was not a constance, same goes with "x", they were not a constance but variables, but in some in 3D they are constance ? for $y = x$ we derivated it with respect to $x$ so dy/dx = 1. But here the function is "z" but it is derivated in respect of "z" ? not in a picked variable?

Also isn't f(x) and y the same ? It's like if I write y is equal to y(x). The same thing I guess ?

Comment: @Jackob2001 The functions aren't constants, but they act like constants if they aren't the variable that the function isn't being differentiated with respect to. In my example I said to differentiate with respect to $z$ and the other variables will act like constants, but I could also differentiate with respect to $y$ and $x$ and $z$ will be like constants.

Comment: functions aren't constants but they can act like constants ? I don't understand it. so $x^2+z^2+y^2$ isn't exactly a function they need to be equal something. One more question and I will pin your answer as solved :) Usually when I write a function I need to get rid of everything that is "connected" to "y" like $2y = x$ I need to get rid of  2 next to "y" or $y^2 = x$ i need to get rid of ^2 to draw this function in the graph. So having dy/dx = 2x I draw it like it is $y = 2x$ which is wierd. Like in the answer below

Comment: @Jackob2001 Don't worry about this until you get into Multivariable Calculus. Now for your second question, when you graph a function on a calculator it is normal to put $y$ for any function, even if there are other functions labeled as $y$. The correct notation is $y'=2x$ since $y=x^2$

Comment: But $y' = 2x$ isn't the same as $y = 2x$ but we draw graph like it is $y = 2x$. Sorry for repeating myself. I don't understand why I can draw it like it is just a simple function without any additional things like $2y$ or $y^2$ etc.  I had to get rid of them to draw a it into a graph. Also I still don't get it whether a function is a function or a constant. As promised I am pinning this answer.

Comment: @Jackob2001 You are correct, it isn't the same. But calculators give the variable $y$ to all functions. It is very confusing but we have to accept it. Also, you could use https://www.desmos.com/ to graph a relation like $y^2=x$ where you don't have to remove the exponent or coefficient or anything. "Whether a function is a function or constant" You could look at 3blue1brown's videos on multivariable calculus, he clears things up a lot.

Comment: I do watch 3blue1brown videos but some videos are not that clear but I do like his videos. What did I mean is not about calculators, but how mathematically it should be done I guess. Like when I draw graph by hand. Usually I should use the variable "y" without any additional things, and dy/dx is an additional thing. $y'=2x$ isn't a "clear", "y" but I do draw it like it is just an equation $y = 2x$

Comment: What do I mean is that when I was in school they've told me to always clear any additional things that are in "y" of "f(x)", because to draw a function in the graph I have to use clear functions. I know that calculators differently goes with "y", but I am saying about correct way of drawing functions in the graph. Because now the derivative is drawn the same way as if $y' = 2x$ is the same as $y = 2x$. Which doesn't make sense because "y" has something in it $dy/dx$

Comment: Am I right ? I just don't know how to interpret it.

Comment: @Jackob2001 You are right. I am actually starting to get confused about function graphing now. Remember that $y$ is used for all functions, so saying that $y=x^2$ and $y=2x$ at the same time shouldn't be considered equal. I couldn't make this any clearer, sorry about this.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, taking a derivative does not mean you just put $\mathrm dx$ on the right side of an expression.
To take a derivative, you must first know that you have a *function*, for example, the function that takes any input (for example, a number $x$) and returns the square of the input number (the number $x^2$ if we continue with the same example of an input).
Some people like to write a description of this function thus:
$x \mapsto x^2,$ meaning, if you put $x$ in you will get $x^2$ out.

When studying calculus we often just write $x^2$ and say that it is a function applied to the variable $x.$
Now we can take the derivative of that function with respect to the named input variable, $x,$ which is sometimes written
$$ \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} x^2 \qquad \text{or}
 \qquad \frac{\mathrm d (x^2)}{\mathrm dx} $$
(never $x^2 \,\mathrm dx$, which is something else entirely).
And from the rule for $x^n$ from your basic differentiation formulas,
setting $n = 2,$ we have
$$\frac{\mathrm d (x^2)}{\mathrm dx} = 2x. $$

Now if you take the equation
$$ y = x^2 $$
and differentiate both sides, you get
$$ \frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} = \frac{\mathrm d (x^2)}{\mathrm dx}. $$

The right side, we know, is just $2x.$ The left side is simply a way of writing
"the derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$," and when we replace the right side of the equation with the equal value $2x,$ we get
$$ \frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} = 2x. $$

This is telling you, literally, that the derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$ is $2x.$
It is just that simple.
Now as long as $y$ is defined by $y = x^2,$ wherever you need the derivative of $y$ you can write $2x,$ because it is an equal quantity.

---

For your next example, $y^2 = x,$ you show a way to express $y$ as a function of $x,$
that is, you get an equation (or two equations, as it turns out) with just $y$ on the left side and some expression of $x$ on the right.
To put it informally, you want to "remove" the square that was applied to $y.$

You can do that kind of thing with derivatives too, that is, "remove" a derivative applied to $y$, so if you start with

$$ \frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} = 2x $$

then you end with

$$ y = x^2 + C $$

where $C$ is a constant. (The constant $C$ is because the answer is not unique, much like you have $y = \sqrt x$ and $y = -\sqrt x$ as alternative answers in your example.)

The process of turning $2x$ into $x^2 + C$ is called *integration*.

---

For more complicated situations where you have $y$ as a function of $z$ and $z$ as a function of $x,$ you need the *chain rule*, which is a basic theorem of differentiation but is not in the list you showed.

---

In response to a comment:

It can sometimes happen that we try to make one letter serve too many tasks in a math exercise. If you use an equation like $y = x^2$ to define $y$ as a function of $x$ then of course it will be very unnatural to try to plot any other function on the same graph. Even if you want to plot the derivative of the function on a separate graph, if you have defined the function this way using the letter $y$ then you still must face the fact that the derivative of $y$ cannot also be called $y.$

There are two ways to get around this. One is that you allow the vertical axis to be called something other than $y.$
There is nothing wrong with that; in more advanced math this is often done, and the horizontal axis may be called something other than $x$ as well.
The conventional labels $x$ and $y$ on a graph are just easy conventions to use when we don't want to take the trouble to say why we are choosing different labels for the axes of a graph.

Another way is to use explicit functional notation to describe a function rather than writing equations with different names of variables on each side.
For example, the function that outputs the square of the input can be named $f$ and defined by

$$  f(x) = x^2. $$

Now the derivative of this function can be named $f'$. We don't even have to say "derivative with respect to $x$" because $f'$ is the derivative of $f$ with respect to whatever is given to $f$ as its input. For the function $f(x) = x^2,$ the derivative is

$$ f'(x) = 2x. $$

I like this notation because it makes it clear that $f$ is a function and its derivative $f'$ is also a function. Also, I do not feel it is too awkward or confusing to graph both of these functions on one graph.
I will simply label one of the functions $y = f(x)$ and label the other
$y = f'(x).$ In this case I don't consider $y = f(x)$ to be the definition of a function (rather, $f(x) = x^2$ is the definition of the function);
$y = f(x)$ merely describes how I am going to *plot* the function.
And when I write $y = f'(x)$ it describes how I am going to plot another function.

In summary: in order to be able to plot both a function and its derivative on a graph with $x$ on the horizontal axis and $y$ on the vertical axis, **do not use** the letter $y$ when defining the function. Use a different notation.

Comment: I have one more question. 
isn't it that if I want to draw this function into a graph I always have to have "y" instead of "y^2" or "dy/dx" ? I was taught that I always have to have single "y" without anything and then I can draw a function into a graph. But here I have something in "y" like "dy/dx" and I draw this function "2x" like it was just a simple equation like "y=2x" , why ?